# pyspark Could not find valid SPARK_HOME

Tags: ubuntu, pyspark, environment-variables

While trying to setup and run pyspark, i get the below error:

```
tom@tom-OptiPlex-3060:~$ pyspark
Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching ['/home', '/home/tom/.local/bin']
/home/tom/.local/bin/pyspark: line 24: /bin/load-spark-env.sh: No such file or directory
/home/tom/.local/bin/pyspark: line 77: /bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory
```

But if I go inside the directory `/usr/lib/spark/bin` - `pyspark` works

what am I missing here?

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle  
export SBT_HOME=/usr/share/sbt-launcher-packaging/bin/sbt-launch.jar  
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/lib/spark
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$SBT_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python2.7
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: Clearly it's ignoring your environment. Have you installed `pyspark` via pip? At which point do you set variables?

Comment: I have tried installing pyspark via pip as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have 2 different pyspark installations. pyspark is using the installation in `/home/tom/.local/bin/pyspark` instead of the one in `/usr/lib/spark/bin`.

Probably you installed manually in `/usr/lib/spark` and the other via pip. As you want to use `/usr/lib/spark`. Please uninstall the pip one, add `/usr/lib/spark/bin` to your path and it should work

Answer (score 2):

I faced this error when I organiszed my python code into packages/modules and when I do some imports from one package to another.

If I have simple script without any packages `SPARK_HOME` is in `os.environ` and equals to `/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client` (your value can be different, just `print(os.environ['SPARK_HOME']` to know).

Simple setting this variable in problematic functions/packages where it fails did not help:

```
import os
os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = '/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client'
```

In my case I solved it by passing this parameter to `spark-submit`:

```
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SPARK_HOME=/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client
```

(additional info which can help: I use `yarn` as master)